# how to mask part of an image using opencv.js

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, contour

What seems to be a simple step in OpenCV in python turns out a hurdle in opencv.js. I am trying to mask a section on image with white color, reference image below. In Python it is super simple.
[image]

below is the line of code in python:

```
image = cv.imread('imagefile')
x = 180
y = 180
w = 70
h = 35
image[(y+h):y, x:(x+w)] = [255, 255, 255]
```

Here **image[(y+h):y, x:(x+w)] = [255, 255, 255]** is doing the trick of masking the part of the image with white color

Could someone help me how to achieve this in opencv.js
below is code in java script.

```
let img = cv.imread('imagefile')
let x = 180
let y = 180
let w = 70
let h = 35
let image_width = 511
let image_height = 511
---
what should be the code here to achieve the desired result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used cv.rectangle to draw the filled white rectangle to achieve this result:

```
let mat = cv.imread(imgElement);
let point1 = new cv.Point(240, 240);
let point2 = new cv.Point(360, 290);
cv.rectangle(mat, point1, point2, [255, 255, 255, 255], -1);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);
mat.delete();
```

[image]

[image]